# memcache limit app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I have categories with (infinite possible levels but will definitely be kept under a 1000) and I'm wondering what is the limit to the memcache in the following instance (generally when caching on a single key):

```
all_categories = Categories.all().fetch(1000)
memcache.set('categories', serialize_entities(all_categories))
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview#Limits):

> Maximum size of a cached value: 1 megabyte

So, if `all_categories` is less than 1 megabyte in size, you'll fit within the limit.

Comment: ah, thank you. Is there anyway to calculate beforehand if it will hit the limit?

Comment: nevermind. 8 bytes * 8 model fields * 1500 (worst case scenario) = 96000 bytes = 0.0915527. far more than I will ever need. thanks